# Validate single Model in Multiple Model ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

How can i validate single model in multiple model

Here are my two Model
ModelA

```
public class ModelA
{
    [Display(Name = "Test1")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Test1 is required.")]
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
}
```

My Second Model ModelB

```
public class ModelB
{
    [Display(Name = "Test2")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Test2 is required.")]
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

My Main Model

```
public class MainModel
{
    public ModelA ModelA { get; set; }
    public ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test1", "SubmitModel", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TestForm", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ModelA.Test1, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.ModelA.Test1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ModelB.Test2, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.ModelB.Test2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <input type="submit" value="next" />
}
```

My Controller 
where my problem exists
I have to validate a single model

```
public PartialViewResult Test1(MainModel model)
{
    if (TryValidateModel(model.ModelA)) // This will validate both model at a time not a single model 
    {
        return PartialView("Index", model);
    }
    return PartialView("Index");
}
```

How can i validate only one model 
For eg if Textbox Text one is empty i have to validate only one model at a time means ModelA at this stage

Comment: `TryValidateModel()` is not even really necessary. The `DefaultModelBinder` has already validated the `MainModel` and added errors to `ModelState` for both `ModelA` and `ModelB`

Comment: Its not really clear what you mean by _if Textbox Text one is empty i have to validate only one_, or what your trying to achieve with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below:

```
public PartialViewResult Test1(MainModel model)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ModelB.Test1)
    {
        ModelState.Remove("Model.ModelB.Test2");
        if (TryValidateModel(model.ModelA)) 
        {
            return PartialView("Index", model);
        }
    }
    return PartialView("Index");
}
```

But it is totally unclear why you would need something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The DefaultModelBinder will validate all for you when it make the bind.
ModelState.IsValid set if all conditions are OK at MainModel objects.

```
public PartialViewResult Test1(MainModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)  
    {
        return PartialView("Index", model);
    }
    return PartialView("Index");
}
```